# Passing http link to vlc as command line argument

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome, firefox, vlc-media-player

When I type `vlc http://192.168.1.2/new video.mkv` into cmd, vlc tries opening two files. The first is `http://192.168.1.2/new` and the other is `video.mkv`. Is it the space in the file name that is causing trouble? If so why and how can I fix it? I noticed when I put that link as an anchor in a html page and use firefox to open it using custom URI scheme, firefox replaces the space with %20 and the file open just fine. When I do the same through chrome, it doesn't replace the space and vlc tries to open two different files. This is how I wrote my anchor tag.

```
<a href="uritest:http://192.168.1.2/new video.mkv">Video</a>
```

Comment: Yes, it is the space that is causing the problem. You need to quote the argument - I think double-quote should work on most operating systems.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. But when I replace the space with %20, it works regardless of the quotation mark and chrome likes it as well in the anchor tag.

Comment: Typing `vlc "http://192.168.1.2/new video.mkv"` should work for command line. For links, it looks like you found the answer yourself - transforming special characters to HTML entities.

Comment: Typing `vlc "http://192.168.1.2/new video.mkv"` doesn't actually work. I think this has to do with the nginx server I just installed. Maybe tweaking some setting would solve this. Note: When I say it doesn't work I mean vlc parses the argument as a single source but cannot actually open the file. I should have been clearer.

Comment: I have confirmed your finding: I know you can't use blanks in a URI on the web, but I thought it would work on a local network, since it does work with a `file://` address. Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs may not contain a blank literal - this has to be URLencoded: `http://192.168.1.2/new%20video.mkv` (In addition to that you might need shell quoting, e.g. "http://192.168.1.2/new%20video.mkv")

The reason this works when you paste it into a browser is, that the browser does the URLencoding for you.